# Why is My Machine Not Importing Adafruit_I2CDevice Library?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to write a program in Arduino. My troubles arise when I am trying to import the Adafruit_ADS1x15 library. I have made sure it is part of my downloaded libraries (such as LiquidCrystal and Wire) and have correctly imported it using #include <Adafruit_ADS1x15.h>.

Yet my machine is returning a "no such file or directory" error when it executes #include <Adafruit_I2CDevice.h>. In other words, my machine cannot find the Adafruit_I2CDevice library.

I believe my machine has properly accessed Adafruit_ADS1x15, but I don't think/know if Adafruit_I2CDevice is installed on my machine.

[my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us1sn.png)
[my installed libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ6R0.png)

I have tried looking into the github documentation to see what was included when I downloaded Adafruit_ADS1x15. However there were no Adafruit_I2CDevice header files included in it.

After that, I thought I would have to download the Adafruit_I2CDevice library by itself but I couldn't find it in Arduino's catalog of libraries. In other words, I don't know if I can download Adafruit_I2CDevice from Arduino.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also: [arduino.se].

Comment: Adafruit has many libraries and the most of them has dependencies with another. Just install anything it spills it's missing (sometimes it's a long run)

Comment: Btw, when I tried to install it and it even asked me to install all dependencies (eg Adafruit_BusIO) so unless you've used other button, it should be there;

Comment: yup, figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Found out that `Adafruit_I2C` is a helper library to `Adafruit_S1x15`. Downloaded `Adafruit_BusIO` and it worked.